# Make various requests using nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I'm using nightmarejs to scrape a website. First, i make a request to fetch some links, which lead to another page with more information that i also want. I've separated it in two functions:

```
const { csvFormat } = require('d3-dsv');
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const url = 'https://lojaonline.claro.com.br/celular';

function getUrls (){
    console.log('Extraindo Links...');
    const nightmare = new Nightmare({show: true});
    var p1 = '51030';
    var p2 = '560';
    try{
        nightmare.goto(url).wait('input[id="edit-cep-part1"]')
                           .type('input[id="edit-cep-part1"]', p1)
                           .wait('input[id="edit-cep-part2"]')
                           .type('input[id="edit-cep-part2"]', p2)
                           .click('input[value="Confirmar"]')
                           .wait('#products-container .products-list').evaluate(function(){

            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.offer')).map(element => element.href);            

        }).end()
        .then(function(result){

            var listaUrls = Object.values(result);

            return listaUrls;

        })
        .then(function(listaUrls){
            listaUrls.forEach(function(link){
                console.log('Pegando preços de ' + link);
                getPrecos(link);
            });
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
};

function getPrecos(endereco) {
    console.log('Extraindo preços...');
    const nightmare = new Nightmare({gotoTimeout: 999999999});
    var p1 = '51030';
    var p2 = '560';
    try{

         nightmare.goto(endereco).wait('input[id="edit-cep-part1"]')
                                .type('input[id="edit-cep-part1"]', p1)
                                .wait('input[id="edit-cep-part2"]')
                                .type('input[id="edit-cep-part2"]', p2)
                                .click('input[value="Confirmar"]')
                                .wait('#plans-tab').evaluate(function(){

            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.body')).map(element => element.innerText);          

        }).end()
        .then(function(result){

            var listaPrecos = Object.values(result);

            console.log(listaPrecos);
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
};

getUrls();
```

It works for the most part. Some requests are successful and i'm able to get the information but some requests are timed out after 30seconds:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: .wait() for #plans-tab timed out after 30000msec.
```

I have to wait, input and click because this particular website asks for a zip code before displaying the data. And if i do show : true inside the getPrecos function, 20 instances of electron will pop up. What am i doing wrong here?

Is there a way to only fire a request after the previous one is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using forEach to loop thru the list, if you want them to grab data one by one, then you should use `for...of` and `async await` or some promise library with concurrency support.

```
listaUrls.forEach(function(link) {
  console.log("Pegando preços de " + link);
  getPrecos(link);
});
```

The above snippet can be turned with async await and for loop like below.

```
// other part of code
.then(async function(listaUrls) { // <-- async function
  for(const link of listaUrls){
      console.log("Pegando preços de " + link);
      await getPrecos(link); // <-- go thru the link one by one
  }
});
```